# How do you designate audio device channels when using AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, objective-c++

I am attempting to designate output channels of an audio interface for sending audio during video playback on macOS. I am using AVPlayer to play a video file:

```
auto player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]; // playerItem created from a file path
player.audioOutputDeviceUniqueID = deviceID; // deviceID determined by passing kAudioObjectPropertyName to AudioObjectGetPropertyData and inspecting device name, e.g. "Babyface Pro"

/* select hardware channels? */

[player play];
```

The `AVPlayer` defaults to playing channels 1/2 of my Babyface Pro, but I'd like to select, for instance, channels 3/4. I cannot select these channel routes globally (i.e. through TotalMix FX) since I am using more than one `AVPlayer` and selecting separate channels for each.
I came across a [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601656/accessing-multiple-audio-hardware-outputs-channels-using-avfoundation-and-swift), however the question did not require playing video, only audio.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @HenningHall I'm afraid not. Eager to learn though!